# It is possible to write a formula for the coefficients of a polynomial, given its roots?

Tags: polynomials, induction, roots

Imagine you are given a polynomial in the following form:
$$
P_n(x) = \prod_{k=0}^n (x-a_k) 
$$
And I would like to find a general expression for this polynomial, in the form of:
$$
P_n(x)=c_nx^n+c_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+c_1x+c_0
$$
And find a formula for $c_n$.

I've tried to compute the first few cases. For $n = 2$:
$$
x^{2-0} - (a_0+a_1)x^{(2-1)}+a_0 a_1x^{(2-2)} \\ \;\\
x^2 - (a_0+a_1)x+a_0 a_1x
$$
For $n=3$:
$$
x^{3-0} - (a_0+a_1+a_2)x^{3-1} + (a_0 a_1 + a_0 a_2 + a_1 a_2)x^{3-2} - (a_0 a_1 a_2)x^{3-3}
$$
For $n=4$:
$$
x^{4-0} - (a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3)x^{4-1} +
(a_0 a_1 + a_0 a_2 + a_0 a_3 + a_1 a_2 + a_1 a_3 + a_2 a_3)x^{4-2} +
(a_0 a_1 a_2 + a_0 a_1 a_3 + a_0 a_2 a_3 + a_1 a_2 a_3)x^{4-3} - (a_0 a_1 a_2 a_3)x^{4-4}
$$
The pattern the coeficients are making its easy to see. For example: for $n=4$ the coeficient of $x^2 = x^{4 - 2}$, are the different pairs of roots that you can make with 4 different possibilities (in this case, 4 total roots) without repeating and without taking into account the order (that is, that the pair $(1, 2)=(2, 1)$). The following expression:
$$
a_0 a_1 + a_0 a_2 + a_0 a_3 + a_1 a_2 + a_1 a_3 + a_2 a_3
$$
Can associated the to the pairs:
$$
\{(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)\}
$$
To see the pattern more clearly.

For the coefficient of $x^k = x^{n - m}$, we can affirm, by induction, that it will contain the sum of all differents groups of size $m$, that could be made with $n$ different roots; without repetition, and not taking into account order. Also, I could see that the numbers of terms that accompanies each monomial of $x$, follows a Pascal triangle.

But, I'm stuck. I don't know if this formula is even possible to get. Any hint?

Comment: Congratulations, you've rediscovered the [*elementary symmetric polynomials*](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial)!

Comment: Good observations, and a nicely asked question (+1). What you ended up with is known as [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).